# Colloquium without proceeding

Tags: publications, proceedings

I presented at a postgraduate colloquium last month, and I indeed think they will publish proceedings in a short post-colloquium. However, a month afterward, no proceedings were published on the website, and the website has been taken down. So, the only way to inquire is to approach the host. They told me they are on their way to making a book, and the submitted paper will be a chapter in the book. Is it common for this to happen in academia?

Comment: What field are you in? That will change the answer. In my field it is very common for small conferences to never formally publish proceedings. However, based on the fact that you are saying the "submitted paper" might be published as a book chapter, I assume this is CS or something similar and the rules are different over on that side of things.

Comment: And, what field was the conference in? My colloquia don't have proceedings, so I wouldn't be surprised if some random CS person once applied to one and then was confused when no proceedings happened.

Answer (score 2):

What is common in academia is that there is a [tremendous amount of variation](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/75368). It is also common that "a month" is like a nano-second.

Everything you describe is reasonable, and perhaps normal, though "common" might be a value judgement. A book takes quite a while to produce since the publisher has lots to do.

If you have access to the colloquium chair(s) ask them for an update and an estimate of when the book might appear.

Even long standing conferences with regularly published proceedings can take a while for those final proceedings to appear.

Your expectations were overly optimistic.

Comment: *can take a while* --- This might not be exactly on-target for an extreme example, but ["This series of four books collects the seminal papers from those proceedings, together with extensive unpublished material ..."](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1108920225) might be a 40+ year example.